# Why does the align environment right-align by default?

Tags: align

If you use the `align` environment without any `&` characters, it right-aligns your equations.  Who ever right-aligns equations?

Comment: who ever aligns anything without specifying an alignment point?  In an align the part before the `&` is right aligned towards the alignment point the part after the `&` is left aligned. that's how the alignment works. You have a display with only the left hand side of each row.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use an `align` or `align*` environment and don't provide one or more `&` markers for each and every row, you're probably misusing the environment. (If you want to center the rows, use a `gather` or `gather*` environment.) Don't expect the software to bail you out and somehow intuit -- correctly, no less... -- where the alignment points are supposed to go.

Right-aligning the rows that are lacking `&` characters, then, is `align`'s way of delivering a powerful and difficult-to-ignore visual message -- the equivalent of "Uh oh, I think you've messed up." Much more powerful, for sure, than issuing a warning message -- which many (most?) users tend to ignore anyway, right? Of course, if for some reason a user does want to right-align the row(s), then that's what he/she gets -- without being bombarded with patronizing warning messages.

The upshot: If you do not provide `&` alignment markers in each and every row of an `align` or `align*` environment, you should almost certainly not be using this environment to begin with.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the `gather` environment - that's the functionality I was looking for.